# Neuraxle AutoML - Why is it erroring?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neuraxle

I am experimenting with Neuraxle following the AutoML example.
The unmodified example works fine.
When i modify it to include my own pipeline components ahead of the `ChooseOneStepOf(classifiers)` it fails and I dont understand why.

```
from neuraxle.base import BaseTransformer
from neuraxle.pipeline import Pipeline
from neuraxle.hyperparams.space import HyperparameterSpace
from neuraxle.steps.numpy import NumpyRavel
from neuraxle.steps.output_handlers import OutputTransformerWrapper
from typing import List

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from neuraxle.pipeline import Pipeline
from neuraxle.union import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# sklearn classifiers, and sklearn wrapper for neuraxle
from neuraxle.steps.sklearn import SKLearnWrapper
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, ExtraTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier, LogisticRegression

# neuraxle distributions
from neuraxle.hyperparams.distributions import Choice, RandInt, Boolean, LogUniform

from neuraxle.steps.flow import ChooseOneStepOf
from neuraxle.base import BaseTransformer, ForceHandleMixin
from neuraxle.metaopt.auto_ml import ValidationSplitter
from neuraxle.metaopt.callbacks import ScoringCallback
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from neuraxle.metaopt.callbacks import MetricCallback
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, precision_score, recall_score
from neuraxle.metaopt.auto_ml import InMemoryHyperparamsRepository
from neuraxle.plotting import TrialMetricsPlottingObserver
from neuraxle.metaopt.tpe import TreeParzenEstimatorHyperparameterSelectionStrategy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from neuraxle.metaopt.auto_ml import AutoML
import os

classifiers: List[BaseTransformer] = [
    SKLearnWrapper(DecisionTreeClassifier(), HyperparameterSpace({
        'criterion': Choice(['gini', 'entropy']),
        'splitter': Choice(['best', 'random']),
        'min_samples_leaf': RandInt(2, 5),
        'min_samples_split': RandInt(1, 3)
    })).set_name('DecisionTreeClassifier'),
    Pipeline([
        OutputTransformerWrapper(NumpyRavel()),
        SKLearnWrapper(RidgeClassifier(), HyperparameterSpace({
            'alpha': Choice([(0.0, 1.0, 10.0), (0.0, 10.0, 100.0)]),
            'fit_intercept': Boolean(),
            'normalize': Boolean()
        }))
    ]).set_name('RidgeClassifier'),
    Pipeline([
        OutputTransformerWrapper(NumpyRavel()),
        SKLearnWrapper(LogisticRegression(), HyperparameterSpace({
            'C': LogUniform(0.01, 10.0),
            'fit_intercept': Boolean(),
            'dual': Boolean(),
            'penalty': Choice(['l1', 'l2']),
            'max_iter': RandInt(20, 200)
        }))
    ]).set_name('LogisticRegression')
]


class ColumnSelectTransformer(BaseTransformer, ForceHandleMixin):

    def __init__(self, required_columns):
        BaseTransformer.__init__(self)
        ForceHandleMixin.__init__(self)
        self.required_columns = required_columns

    def inverse_transform(self, processed_outputs):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
            X = pd.DataFrame(X)
        return X[self.required_columns]


columns = ['BEDCERT', 'RESTOT', 'INHOSP', 'CCRC_FACIL',
           'SFF', 'CHOW_LAST_12MOS', 'SPRINKLER_STATUS',
           'EXP_TOTAL', 'ADJ_TOTAL']

simple_features = Pipeline([ColumnSelectTransformer(columns),
                            SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,
                                          strategy='mean')])

categorical_features = Pipeline([ColumnSelectTransformer(['OWNERSHIP', 'CERTIFICATION']),
                                 OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
                                 ])
business_features = FeatureUnion([simple_features,
                                  categorical_features])

p: Pipeline = Pipeline([
    business_features,
    ChooseOneStepOf(classifiers)
])


validation_splitter = ValidationSplitter(test_size=0.20)

scoring_callback = ScoringCallback(
    metric_function=accuracy_score,
    name='accuracy',
    higher_score_is_better=False,
    print_metrics=False
)

callbacks = [
    MetricCallback('f1', metric_function=f1_score, higher_score_is_better=True, print_metrics=False),
    MetricCallback('precision', metric_function=precision_score, higher_score_is_better=True, print_metrics=False),
    MetricCallback('recall', metric_function=recall_score, higher_score_is_better=True, print_metrics=False)
]

hyperparams_repository = InMemoryHyperparamsRepository(cache_folder='cache')

hyperparams_repository.subscribe(TrialMetricsPlottingObserver(
    plotting_folder_name='metric_results',
    save_plots=False,
    plot_trial_on_next=False,
    plot_all_trials_on_complete=True,
    plot_individual_trials_on_complete=False
))

hyperparams_optimizer = TreeParzenEstimatorHyperparameterSelectionStrategy(
    number_of_initial_random_step=10,
    quantile_threshold=0.3,
    number_good_trials_max_cap=25,
    number_possible_hyperparams_candidates=100,
    prior_weight=0.,
    use_linear_forgetting_weights=False,
    number_recent_trial_at_full_weights=25
)

tmpdir = 'cache'
if not os.path.exists(tmpdir):
    os.makedirs(tmpdir)

n_trials = 10
n_epochs = 10

auto_ml = AutoML(
    pipeline=p,
    validation_splitter=validation_splitter,
    refit_trial=True,
    n_trials=n_trials,
    epochs=n_epochs,
    cache_folder_when_no_handle=str(tmpdir),
    scoring_callback=scoring_callback,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    hyperparams_repository=hyperparams_repository
)


def generate_classification_data():
    # data_inputs, expected_outputs = make_classification(
    #     n_samples=10000,
    #     n_repeated=0,
    #     n_classes=3,
    #     n_features=4,
    #     n_clusters_per_class=1,
    #     class_sep=1.5,
    #     flip_y=0,
    #     weights=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    # )

    data = pd.read_csv('./ml-data/providers-train.csv', encoding='latin1')
    fine_counts = data.pop('FINE_CNT')
    fine_totals = data.pop('FINE_TOT')
    cycle_2_score = data.pop('CYCLE_2_TOTAL_SCORE')

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        data,
        fine_counts > 1,
        test_size=0.20
    )

    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = generate_classification_data()

auto_ml = auto_ml.fit(X_train, y_train)



Output as follows:-
```

> /Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/bin/python /Users/simon/Dev/wqu_q4/main.py
> new trial: { "ChooseOneStepOf": { "choice": "RidgeClassifier" } }
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0> trial 1/10
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0>
> <neuraxle.metaopt.trial.Trial object at 0x134a469d0> Traceback (most
> recent call last): File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 785, in _fit_data_container repo_trial_split =
> self.trainer.execute_trial( File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/trial.py",
> line 290, in **exit** raise exc_val File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 785, in _fit_data_container repo_trial_split =
> self.trainer.execute_trial( File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 595, in execute_trial self.print_func('success trial {} score:
> {}'.format( File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/trial.py",
> line 570, in **exit** raise exc_val File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 574, in execute_trial trial_split_description =
> _get_trial_split_description( File "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 876, in _get_trial_split_description
> json.dumps(repo_trial.hyperparams, sort_keys=True, indent=4) File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/**init**.py",
> line 234, in dumps return cls( File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py",
> line 201, in encode chunks = list(chunks) File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py",
> line 431, in _iterencode yield from _iterencode_dict(o,
> _current_indent_level) File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py",
> line 405, in _iterencode_dict yield from chunks File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py",
> line 438, in _iterencode o = _default(o) File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py",
> line 179, in default raise TypeError(f'Object of type
> {o.**class**.**name**} ' TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON
> serializable During handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/Users/simon/Dev/wqu_q4/main.py", line 210, in  auto_ml =
> auto_ml.fit(X_train, y_train) File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/base.py",
> line 3475, in fit new_self = self.handle_fit(data_container, context)
> File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/base.py",
> line 980, in handle_fit new_self =
> self._fit_data_container(data_container, context) File
> "/Users/simon/venvs/wqu_q4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/neuraxle/metaopt/auto_ml.py",
> line 802, in _fit_data_container repo_trial_split=repo_trial_split,
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'repo_trial_split' referenced before
> assignment Process finished with exit code 1

---

Comment: What is the version of Neuraxle ? Can you try updating it maybe ? I don't see the reason why this would fail. It seems like it's trying to use a variable that doesn't exist, which is very weird. Perhaps reset your .pyc precompiled files, or try reinstalling your venv ?

Comment: 0.5.6 within pycharm which is odd as Github indicates you are only at 0.5.5
I wonder if its related to my ColumnTransformer not returning data in the right format does it need to be in a numpy array or can i return a pandas dataframe? I only just created the virtual env for this purpose but can retry.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes that may help you with your current problem:

1. the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'repo_trial_split' referenced before assignment" is an error that happens when something crashes within a Pipeline in an AutoML loop. You should have the real error logged somewhere above the one you posted here. Also, Neuraxle version 0.5.7 (which isnt release yet but available on github) fixes this by adding an argument called "continue_loop_on_error" which you should set to False.
2. You seem to be using a ForceHandleMixin for your ColumnSelectTransformer instance. Using ForceHandleMixin means you should define the following functions _fit_data_container, _transform_data_container and _fit_transform_data_container and not fit/fit_transform/transform.
3. You probably need to write a Neuraxle class to wrap scikit's SimpleImputer.

Hope this helps you. Feel free to post an update here once you've made these changes and I'll be glad to help you. You can also post on Neuraxle's Slack I might be quicker to answer there.

Cheers!

p.s. On another note, I'll be making 0.5.7 release in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will investigate further